# Sharing design challenges done for another employer

Tags: hiring-process

I am a UX designer, and it's common for employers to request that a designer complete a design challenge - basically a quick prompt that can be done in 2-3 days, showing off the designer's thought process and ability to work quickly. Typically, these challenges do not involve anything related to the company (sometimes they are not even in the same vertical), so there are no NDAs involved.

Is it okay to show the design challenges I've completed in the past to potential employers? I would ideally like to reuse my existing work instead of spending days doing a new challenge from scratch. I doubt that "can I just send you something else" is very diplomatic, but I think I can precede the request for a challenge by saying "hey take a look at some challenges I've done."

If so, is it okay to display these challenges on my portfolio, publicly?

Comment: "is it OK" in what sense? Legally? Ethically? Whether it will help or hurt your job search (or neither)? I think the answers are yes, maybe, maybe not, respectively; I can easily see a potential employer worrying about whether you understand implied confidentiality...

Comment: Ethically, I guess. Legally, I'm reasonably sure I'm in the clear.

Comment: Can you show off work you authored in the past as part of your portfolio that is not under contract? The answer is yes.

Comment: I guess my question is more like, *should* I? Will employers think it's weird if I do this? Will they think that I am trying to get out of doing *their* challenges?

Comment: Why don't you ask the employer if you can reuse the work?

Comment: I guess I should specify: I'm more concerned about what **other employers** will think about me showing them these challenges. Basically I don't want to keep doing them every time, but I don't know if I can show an old one without coming off as lazy and uncooperative.

Comment: Don't wait for them to ask that you complete a sample and then say "look at this other thing instead"; by the time they ask to do their exercise it's too late. If you have an example of your work, showcase it preemptively in some kind of portfolio.

Comment: My concern would be "If he doesn't get the job, is he going to post a spoiler for our favorite challenge too? Might be safer not to give him the opportunity to do so."

Answer (score 1):

Simple: If you did work and you got paid for it, then it is theirs. That doesn't even preclude you from showing it; if you created a design that appeared on national TV in an ad campaign there seems to be no reason why you couldn't show that to a potential customer. If you did work and didn't get paid, then it is yours and you do with it what you want.

Not wanting to do two days of unpaid work is in no way lazy, on the contrary it is an entirely reasonable thing to do. You must do $x on average per day; if you do unpaid work then you need to charge more than $x a day for paid work, so I'd rather hire someone who keeps their cost down by not doing unpaid work.

Answer (score 0):

As a UX designer, you should be building a portfolio. Present it to prospective companies and if they want you to do something specific, you don't have much choice. I don't think having a portfolio would be looked at as you're being lazy. The difference is, include links or make some reference to the portfolio in your CV and cover letter before they ask you to do some other task.